# How long can you take tetracycline in the treatment of acne?

Tags: medications, antibiotics, acne, staph-infections

I received a prescription on unidox solutab against staphylococcus. I've been taking this drug for 4 months and everything looked fine, acne disappeared 3 months ago. Now akne started to appear again and doctor says that I need to take unidox solutab again during the recent 6 months. Is it reasonable to take it for so long? Won't organism adapt to this antibiotic so that taking it is useless?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doxycycline is a member of tetracycline group and these are antibiotics of choice in moderate to severe acne. For this group, *Martindale pharmacopoeia* states that they should show some improvement after 3 months and that:

> Maximum improvement is said to occur after 3 to 6 months, but treatment may need to continue for 2 or more years.

Antibiotics act by affecting the bacteria causing acne, their mechanism of action is not based on affecting your organism. That's why the organism does not adapt and lessen their effectiveness. However, there is an issue of antimicrobial resistance to antibiotics. To prevent it, it is essential to take your medicines exactly as prescribed: not to skip/miss doses, not to take them with food or medicines and supplements that contain calcium, magnesium, iron, aluminum, zinc and other divalent and trivalent cations.

A concern with prolonged antibiotic use may be their adverse effects. It is important that your therapy as well as your progress is monitored by your physician.